# Mentioning blogs using Tumblr API / PHP SDK

Tags: php, api, tumblr

I'm creating an integration that allows people to post on Tumblr. It seems to work well, except that I can't figure out how to mention people using the API.

Tumblrs docs only mention how to do it using the impossible Neue Post Format, which the PHP SDK doesn't seem to support. The [legacy format](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#post--create-a-new-blog-post-legacy) doesn't show it.

Am I missing something? Or will I have to make manual calls using the new format?

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // composer tumblr/tumblr version 0.4.0

$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$client->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);

$data = array(
  "type" => 'text',
  "body" => $body,
  "tags" => $tagString
);

$client->createPost($blogName, $data);
```

Expected result:

> create a post that has a clickable link to the mentioned person.

Actual result:

> The mentioned name is posted as plain text.

How do I solve this problem?